# Computed observable undefined

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Address is always coming as undefined.

```
var Neighborhood = function(data){

    this.street = ko.observable(data.street);
    this.city = ko.observable(data.city);
    this.address = ko.computed(function(){
        return  this.street + ' ' + this.city;
    },this);

}

var ViewModel = function(){

var streetStr = 'aaa';
var cityStr = 'ccc';

    console.log('street 1 - var: ' + streetStr);


    // Initialize Neighborhood object with data from the given address
    self.Neighborhood = ko.observable({
    street: streetStr,
    city: cityStr});

    console.log('Obj street    : ' + this.Neighborhood().street);
    console.log('Obj address   : ' + this.Neighborhood().address);
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

Comment: It would be appreciated it if you show some more information / your attempted solutions / share your research. Your post currently is a bit concise making it look like a "debug this code for me" post. Note that on Stack Overflow, you can edit your posts at any time to improve / enhance them.

Answer (score 2):

You are not storing an instance of the `Neighborhood` function to the `Neighborhood` observable. Try changing your code to:

```
var Neighborhood = function(data){
    this.street = ko.observable(data.street);
    this.city = ko.observable(data.city);
    this.address = ko.computed(function(){
        return  this.street() + ' ' + this.city();
    });
};

self.Neighborhood = ko.observable(new Neighborhood({
    street: streetStr,
    city: cityStr})
);
```